# My database isn't running all of my migrations, but says the schema number has

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, migration

I was trying to fix a bad migration. I reset my database a couple times and it's just causing further problems, namely that not all my migrations are even running now.

Below are all the migrations, the one that was broken is the one yet to be run. But when I try to do a `rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
undefined method `to_sym' for
nil:NilClass/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:258:in
`column'
```

This is an issue in itself but what is most confusing to me is that the migration to create the simulation table just isn't running. My scheme looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150806192507) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",              limit: 96, default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password", limit: 60, default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Any suggestions as to:

1. The simulations table is not being created when I do a reset and re-migrate.
2. The final migration to remove the verdict column is failing.

These are the migrations I have:

1.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => "", limit: 96
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => "", limit: 60

      t.timestamps

      t.index :email, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

2.

```
class CreateSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Needs the hash column worked out before this is run 
    create_table :simulations do |t|
    t.integer :x_size
    t.integer :y_size
    t.string :verdict
    t.string :arrangement 
    end

    add_reference :simulations, :user, index: true    
  end
end
```

3.

```
class AddOpinionToSimulation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :simulations, :opinion, :hash
  end
end
```

Finally, this is the bad one I was trying to run that started these problems. I have deleted the file to stop it from attempting to be migrated:

```
class RemoveVerdictFromSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :simulations, :verdict
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the full backtrace for the error

Answer (score 1):

There is no table simulations in your schema. If if it's not there, then you'll never be able to run that third migration.

First, refresh your database schema to make sure it's accurate in relation to your database with `rake db:schema:dump`

If there is indeed no simulations table, then first make sure that migration 2 succeeds.

Check schema_migrations table. If there are two rows there, then rails will think that the simulations table got created already, just delete the last entry from this table and migrate again making sure that the simulations table gets created this time, then try again with migration 3

Comment: So when I run rake db:schema:dump then check my 'schema.rb' its still just the user table, am I checking in the wrong place, or how else can I reset it?

Comment: Your 2nd migration has a big number prefix. Check if your schema_migrations table has a row with that same number. If it doesn't then you haven't run that migration, run `rake:db:migrate` and make sure it creates the simulations table. If however, there's an entry in the schema_migrations table with that same number, then you can try with a rollback `rake db:rollback STEP=1` then running the migration again to see if this time the table gets created

Comment: Checking my 'schema.rb' file: the version number it shows is that of the third migration, implying that the simulation table migration ran, but it doesnt have a table for simulations. This is where you wanted me to check yes?

Comment: Ok, in that case do `rake db:rollback STEP=2` then `rake:db:migrate`

Comment: I get this error: rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT  "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Does that happen during rollback or migration?

Comment: rake db:rollback STEP=2

Comment: Ok then you have to change it by hand. Open your SQLite database using any 3rd party software and delete all rows from the `database_schema` table except the one that matches the version number of your first migration

Comment: Can I do this from command line as well, any software recommendations ?

Comment: You'll have to google that, I don't have any experience with SQLite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85393/discussion-between-juan-fuentes-and-nnnnnnnnnndelicious).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this particular error was to go into my SQL database, delete every single version in the schema table. Then I did a

```
rake db:drop
```

I then walked through each version to make sure they migrated in order using:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=<VERSION_NUMBER_FROM_EARLIEST_TO_LATEST>
```

If I ran into an error about a table not existing using:

```
rake db:prepare
```

Seemed to fix it aside from the last problem migration.